# Filter blank CharField in Django Haystack's SearchQuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, whoosh

I need to return all entries in a SearchQuerySet where a certain CharField is blank i.e. an empty string.

In my search_indexes.py I have:

```
sometext = indexes.CharField(model_attr='sometext')
```

I've tried filtering using the usual SQS syntax:

```
SearchQuerySet().filter(sometext__exact='')
SearchQuerySet().filter(sometext__in=['', None])
```

Neither return only the blank entries. The first returns all entries, the second returns none at all.

Am I missing something in my SearchIndex definitions? Is there any way this can be done in Haystack using the Whoosh backend?

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works for me:

```
from haystack.inputs import Raw
r = SearchQuerySet()
r.exclude(sometext=Raw('*'))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
    SomeQuerySet().filter(sometext='')
```

Comment: I believe this is the same as .filter(sometext__exact=''), which I mentioned I tried above

Comment: Is the same... but it works well if database configuration blank = True and null = False

Comment: It works well for a QuerySet filter yes, but not with Haystack's SearchQuerySet - my question's about the latter. Haystack's API docs don't appear to cover it.